# How to get text input that has been rotated by 90 degrees to take up full height of div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to work out how to get my input to take up the whole height of the parent div when its rotated (i.e. I want some one to be able to type as much text in as will fit in the parent div.

I've tried changing both the width and height values of the input to 100% and it doesn't help.

I have it working when the input is not rotated, so there must be some sort of trick I am missing?

HTML

```css
.Yaxis-Label-Container {
    grid-area: Yaxis-Label;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: end;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1000px;
}

#yaxisLabel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 29px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="Yaxis-Label-Container" >

<input
          type="text"
          autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="Yaxis"
          id="yaxisLabel"
          
        />
</div>
```

Comment: Note that an `input type="text"` is limited to 255 characters. In situations where it is possible to type more, use `<textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem as well. All you have to do is use viewport width(vw) and viewport height(vh)

```
input {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

or just try using an id selector if for some reason that selector won't work

```
#input {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

*You won't use 100vw and 100vh you'd have to adjust it to fit the div element, but I can't get it to work any other way.

Comment: An alternative is just to use a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

With your html and css and rotating the div instead of the input it will become this css

```css
.Yaxis-Label-Container {
    border: 1px solid red; /*remove this line, for test only*/
    grid-area: Yaxis-Label;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* input will center in width 1000px */
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: calc(0.5 * (1000px - 100px)); /* half of width minus height */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#yaxisLabel {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 29px;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Yaxis-Label-Container" >
  <input
    type="text"
    autocomplete="off"
    placeholder="Yaxis"
    id="yaxisLabel"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did what bron suggested but found that the yaxis label appeared to be shifted to the left as a result of the rotation

Therefore I had to implement a javascript solution to fix its position on the x co-ordinate

I added a listener to the co-ordinates of the parent div. Everytime it moved (i.e. screen resize) I had to calculate the distance required needed to shift the label element left or right such that it appeared in the right place